# Is it possible to pass the result of a promise as an argument to IIFE

Tags: javascript, promise, iife

I have been refactoring some old code that uses an IIFE to fetch and initiate a set of values.

```
var exampleInitiate = (function exampleInitiate(){
  ..call some backend service
})();
```

Now, as per new requirement, I have to call the same IIFE with an argument, and this argument is actually a result of a promise which itself is invoked much later. I understand that IIFE are immediately invoked, and even if I get the result of the promise, will I be able to call the IIFE again? I understands IIFEs run once only.

I am thinking it will be best to not use the IIFE here as it does not fit here in this case. Would this be correct, or is there indeed a way to call a IIFE passing an argument value from a promise?

Comment: Why not pass the promise itself in, instead of the value of the promise? Since the promise hasn't been invoked yet, it has no value, but you can easily pass the promise into the IIFE and then use it's value when it has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can have couple of options if I understand you correct. First you can pass an argument to IIFE like this:

```
var myPromise = getPromise();

var exampleInitiate = (function exampleInitiate(promise){
  promise.then(function() { ... });
  ..call some backend service
})(myPromise);
```

But I wouldn't call this way clear. I would suggest erase IIFE and use promises as you would normally do:

```
getSomeBackEndResponse().then(function (data) { ... })
```

EDIT: if you IIFE returns promise itself then yes, I think you can't pass in the result of function to itself again, since IIFE is invoked once. Rethink the logic of this chunk of code.